# PyQt - subclassing the QMainWindow to access Gui elements

Tags: python, pyqt4

I use a QStackedWidget and switch between different views.  Each pane is basically a class and should reside in it's own file.

The problem is I want to access a QTableView from the other file without passing it's reference into the constructor.

Main File:

```
class MyApp(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

2nd File

```
from ui_MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow

class LimitsEditor(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, session):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.tblCommonLimits_horizheader = QHeaderView(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.tblCommonLimits_horizheader = QMainWindow.tblLimits.horizontalHeader()
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'QMainWindow' has no attribute 'tblLimits'
```

As you can see, I want to access a table called "tblLimits" that I created in QtDesigner, but I'm unable to get access to it in my second file.

Any suggestions?

(edit for formatting)

I am editing this to show what I am doing that works:

In the main, when instantiating the class:

```
self.LimitsEditor = LimitsEditor(self.ui.tblLimits)
```

In the LimitsEditor file:

```
class LimitsEditor():
    def __init__(self, tblLimits):
        self.tblLimits = tblLimits
```

Now in the main I can access the table as either 'self.ui.tlbLimits' OR 'self.LimitsEditor.tblLimits'
This is how I have been doing it, and it works fine.  It just didn't seem quite right to me, so I was wondering if there was a way to just inherit the knowledge of all the UI elements into another class/subclass.

Comment: I am not clear on what you are trying to do here. e.g: Why do you have *two* main windows?

Comment: Is your goal to access the SAME table instance between those two classes, or just simply to access the individual table for that one class?

Comment: Yes, the goal is access the SAME table instance b/t the classes.  It felt sloppy to pass a reference to the table into the class.  I wanted to move all the details of the table into another class that listens for changes to the table/model (editing in a cell) and then updates a database accordingly.

Comment: I updated the end of the original question to show what I am doing now that works

Comment: Go with option 3 of my answer and set up an event filter. Then your LimitEditor can act like a delegate without storing a ref.  or just stick with ur current way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are trying to do is to have `LimitsEditor` be able to access the exact same table instance being used by MyApp, then this approach you are trying is impossible. The .ui file is a description of a layout of widgets which you apply to your class. When you call setupUi() inside your QMainWindow class, it creates instances. The actual UI module does not contain any references to these instances that you can then access in another file.

You **must** share a reference to the instance from `MyApp` to `LimitsEditor`. This comes down to a design decision. Here are a few suggestions (since I don't know how your app is really organized)

1. Wherever you are managing your stacked widget, you can pass a reference of the table instance to your LimitsEditor
2. Let your `LimitsEditor` be unaware of the table widget, and emit signals, to which your parent objects will listen and manage the table instance in response
3. Set up your `LimitsEditor`  with an [eventsFilter](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qobject.html#eventFilter) for the table (in your parent object). Your LimitsEditor wont directly have a reference to the table, but rather will receive events for it that it can handle.

Referring to the exception that you are seeing, `QMainWindow` is the PyQt4 class and does not contain your custom child widgets. Those are located on the *instance* of your custom class which contains the `setupUi()` call. You would then need to access it via `self.tblLimits`, but again this would be only for the class that actually used the Ui file, not other random classes.

Comment: thanks, I am basically passing a reference of the table into the other class.  The point of the LimitsEditor class is to take a reference to an empty table, call the custom QAbstractTableModel creation, define all the selection/headers/etc of the table and then bind the model to the table

Answer (score 0):

When working with the QtDesigner in PyQt you usually follow the same patter:

1. Create the designer .ui file.
2. Create a class to use it.
3. Ensure that the ui file sets the widgets of your class.

For example:

```
class MyApp(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


class LimitsEditor(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, session):
        super(QMainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.tblCommonLimits_horizheader = QHeaderView(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.tblCommonLimits_horizheader = self.ui.tblLimits.horizontalHeader()
```

Make sure you do access the widget through the instance ui element.

Comment: For some reason that isn't working for me. 
'AttributeError: 'LimitsEditor' object has no attribute 'ui''

Comment: Why would you think this would work? You are treating LimitsEditor like it has anything to do with MyApp. They are two separate classes. `self.ui` exists on MyApp but you didn't do that on the other class

Comment: Sorry, typo! I should hav instantiated the ui in the LimitsEditor, fixing that.